# Drawing Shapes in scala

Tags: scala, composite, shapes

I am having some serious troubles implementing a draw in the scala language.  my current code looks like:

```
package edu.luc.cs.laufer.cs473.shapealgebra

import java.awt.Graphics2D

class Draw {
  def draw(g: Graphics2D)(s: Shape): Unit = s match {
    case Ellipse(hw, hh) => g.drawArc(-hw, -hh, 2 * hw, 2 * hh, 0, 360)
    case Rectangle(w, h) => g.drawRect(0, 0, w, h)
    case Location(x: Int, y: Int, shape: Shape) => {
      g.translate(x, y)
      draw(g)(shape)
      g.translate(0,0)
    }
    case Group(shapes @ _*) => {
      shapes foreach(draw(g)(_))
    }
  }
 }

 object Draw extends Draw {
  def apply(g: Graphics2D) = draw(g)(_)
}
```

The problem here is with my group case.  It does not draw a group of shapes properly.  The two test cases uses the following shapes:

```
val simpleLocation = Location(70, 30, Rectangle(80, 120))
val complexGroup = Location(50, 100,
    Group(
     Ellipse(20, 20),
     Location(150, 50,
        Group(
          Rectangle(50, 30),
          Rectangle(300, 60),
          Location(100, 200,
          Ellipse(50, 50)
         )
       )
     ),
     Rectangle(100, 200)
   )
  )
```

The complex continues to fail and I can't figure out why.

```
package edu.luc.cs.laufer.cs473.shapealgebra

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

import TestFixtures._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestDraw extends FunSuite with BufferedImageEquality {
  test("simple") {
    val s = simpleLocation
    val i = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    Draw(i.createGraphics())(s)
    val j = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    val g = j.createGraphics()
    g.translate(70, 30)
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 80, 120)
    assertEquals(i, j)
  }
  test("complex") {
    val s = complexGroup
    val i = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    Draw(i.createGraphics())(s)
    val j = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    val g = j.createGraphics()
    paintComplexGroup(g)
        assertEquals(i, j)
  }
}
```

The test case is shown above.  I get a "0 did not equal 255" from the result of the unit test.

Comment: We are missing the implementation of Ellipse, Rectangle and Location, so we cannot see what the problem is, nor have you described what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: It didn't really improve the question. We don't know what paintComplexGroup do (not exactly), and we still can't try out for ourselves because we are missing the definition of some classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what `translate` does, the Javadoc says

> "Translates the origin of the Graphics2D context to the point (x, y)
>   in the **current** coordinate system."

So

```
  g.translate(0,0)
```

does nothing. Try

```
  g.translate(-x, -y)
```

Although, if it were me, I wouldn't mess with the Graphics object's origin. I'd modify the `drawRect` and `drawArc` statements to take a location, and pass the location co-ordiates as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are calling `translate` on `g: Graphics2D`, which mutates that object. However, you are not undoing that mutation once you finish drawing the translated objects. Furthermore, there's also the question of whether you expect the translation to be cumulative (for example, the second translation be absolute 200, 150, instead of absolute 150, 50).

Might this the problem you see?

Comment: You mean `translate` rather than `transform`?

Comment: I tried to address the first problem you brought up by changing the code as you can see above.  I still get the same reult from the unit test.  Also, I dont really understand your second point.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Luigi In my defense, it was very late. :-)

Comment: @Matthew You have one location inside the other. The first location will translate to 50, 100. The second says 150, 50. But is that 150, 50 *relative* to 50,100 (ie, absolute 150 + 50, 50 + 100), or not? I don't even know what `Graphics2D` does, much less whether what it does is what you expect.

Comment: by your definition i believe i would say the locations are absolute.  As in NOT the sum of the locations